# How does DZSlides scale viewport contents?

Tags: javascript, css

I like how [DZSlides](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides) uses pixel dimensions and scales them to the viewport size, as it provides some nice predictability for presentations (though I wouldn't want to use it on a regular website).

However, I can't seem to figure out how the scaling works exactly - my own attempts to recreate [the code](https://github.com/paulrouget/dzslides/blob/054cf071bd9d013e1e468d8236e79478ce847da4/template.html#L401) have some annoying quirks, either not taking up the entire height or exhibiting strange vertical offsets:

http://jsfiddle.net/vYA8L/

I'd be grateful for concise explanations of what my example there is missing and how DZSlides actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DZSlides sets `body` to be [800x600 and centered in window](https://github.com/paulrouget/dzslides/blob/054cf071bd9d013e1e468d8236e79478ce847da4/template.html#L208) (comments added by me):

```
body {
    width: 800px; height: 600px;
    margin-left: -400px; margin-top: -300px;  /* these two lines center */
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;  /* body in the window     */
    ...
}
```

and each slide to have [`width: 100%` and `height: 100%`](https://github.com/paulrouget/dzslides/blob/054cf071bd9d013e1e468d8236e79478ce847da4/template.html#L229), meaning the slides inherit their width and height from `body`.

The JavaScript code actually scales `body` to fit the window, and so by extension each slide is scaled to fit as well.

Your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYA8L/1/) updated with these styles will scale correctly.

If you want to scale the slide elements instead of `body`, you can apply the same styles / calculation to the slides ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYA8L/2/)).